# Why does ssh hang after "debug1: loaded 3 keys"

Tags: ssh

Trying to log in to an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 10.04.1.  I can log in just fine, no issues.  A different user, coming from a different network just gets this:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxx [xxxx] port 80.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
```

And then it hangs.

We've tried running sshd on port 22 and port 80

I'm guessing that it's not a firewall problem since the verbose output reports that the connection is established.

I don't see anything in /var/log/auth.log when the failing user connects.  I do see entries when I log in successfully.

Comment: Try adding more debug information: ssh -vvv command line. Also showing us your ssh_config and your .ssh/config could help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a symptom I have seen at regular interval, and I'd wager it is caused by one of the hops between your cloud server and the user's network filtering out ICMP messages indiscriminately, causing path MTU discovery to fail; the key exchange is the first part of the SSH protocol where it is likely that large TCP segments are sent over the socket, and most likely to trigger the problem.

Two easy ways to isolate the problem:  try to make large exchanges over some other protocol between the same hosts (for instance, upload some file over a web form), or artificially force the MTU on the user's host to some value small enough to fit any plausible MTU along the network (~300b).  If the problem pops up during other large transfers and disappears with the smaller MTU, then you've found the culprit.

(The reason that happens is that when an IP packet that has the DF (don't fragment) flag set is transmitted that does not fit through a hop, the hop will respond with an ICMP message; and filtering those ICMP messages out is a common misconfiguration by inexperienced or overly paranoid network admins - so the sending host never knows the path MTU is smaller than it thinks and packets just vanish in the aether).

The bad news is that this is not something that can be fixed at either endpoint in general, but at the hop where the improper filtering is taking place.  You can work around the problem with manually configured MTUs, but that's an ugly hack and is brittle at best.

Answer (score 0):

Can we eliminate the firewall more conclusively from this by turning off the ssh port in the ec2 access control list and seeing what the debug output looks like? I suspect you are right but it would be interesting to see the difference.

Do you have any other access control going on on the instance side? SSH blacklist / whitelists?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old thread, but not satisfactorily answered (IMHO). I got here by Googling, others might too.

I resolved this issue by checking the network config. My SSH client had an obsolete netmask, /24 instead of /22. I updated the config, restarted networking, and it was good.

Comment: If connectivity failed because of a misconfigured netmask it would hang before `Connection established`.